# How to use json parese this content

Tags: json, gson

I got the json string like this,

```
{
    "resultCode": 200,
    "operation": 0,
    "resultMsg": "正常初始化",
    "debugMsg": "",
    "resultCount": 3,
    "result": {
        "operation": 0,
        "verify_key": "6f3e9169e4fcfbe4a52606c013348650",
        "user_id": 41201
    }
}
```

But I want to convert it to,

```
public class ClientResult {
    String result;
    String resultMsg;
    String debugMsg;
    int resultCode;
    int operation;
}
```

.If i use gson.fromJson(result, ClientResult.class),get a exception

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 118

I just want to parse it to String, not Object, because the result field of ClientResut is not same,it maybe a  array sometimes.
the result sometimes like

```js
 {
   "resultCode": 200,
   "operation": 0,
   "resultMsg": "",
   "debugMsg": "",
   "resultCount": 12,
   "result": {
     "id": "4392",
     "pm25": "44",
     "time": "1433403001",
     "l_temperature": "9",
     "h_temperature": "20",
     "c_temperature": "14",
     "weather_icon": "http://60.31.215.212/zsgj/Public/weather/zhenyu.png",
     "tm_l_temperature": "8",
     "tm_h_temperature": "25",
   }
 }
```

So i just want to parse it to a String..

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are doing it wrong, "result" is another json object in your json, You can go with an approach of creating 2 POJOs for your Json which you can use in your GSON.

```
public class Result
{
    private String operation;

    private String verify_key;

    private String user_id;

}
```

and your original class

```
public class ClientResult
{

    private String resultMsg;

    private Result result;

    private String debugMsg;

    private String operation;

    private String resultCount;

private String resultCode;
```

}

Comment: How can the result object be parsed into a string variable? can you let us know an sample String result; variable you actually expecting?